# Foreign Key to Composite Primary Key

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have a problem with foreign keys.

**The master table is:**

```
Course (courseName, courseId)
```

and PK is `courseId`

**The second table is:**

```
Section (sectionId, courseId)
```

and PK is `(sectionId, courseID)`, FK is `courseID reference Course(courseId)`

And the problem table is:

```
GradeReport (studentId, sectionId, courseId, grade)
```

and PK is `(studentID, sectionID, courseID)`

The FK's are

- `courseId reference Course(courseID)`
- `sectionId reference Section(sectionID)`

(**no permisson** for (courseId, sectionId) reference Section(courseId, sectionID))

The first FK is OK! But the second one gives me an error:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the primary key of Section is (sectionId, courseID), the foreign key constraint of GradeReport must be (sectionID, courseID).

In fact you will not need a foreign key constraint on GradeReport referencing Course, since the courseID will be in this foreign key constraint.

Comment: But no permission for GradeReport(sectionID, courseID) reference Section (sectionID, courseID) courseId must be referencing the courseId field of the Course table.

Comment: I do not understand the "(no permisson for (courseId, sectionId) reference Section(courseId, sectionID))" line in your questions.  You stated the error as "ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list" which would happen if you did "sectionId reference Section(courseID, sectionID)" instead of "sectionId reference Section(courseID, sectionID)

Comment: the instructor says that you must reference the courseID only from Course table. not in Section table. So we can only use course table for CourseId.

Comment: In that case, I don't think CourseID is part of the primary key of the Section table.  If the SectionID is an auto increment integer, it will be unique without CourseID.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question fully, but if I had these tables my foreign keys would be:

- Section (which I think is OK for you already)

  ```
  FOREIGN KEY ..name.. REFERENCES Course(CourseID)
  ```
- GradeReport (which is where I think you have the problem)

  ```
  FOREIGN KEY ..name.. REFERENCES Section(SectionID, CourseID)
  ```

You don't need a separate Foreign Key for `GradeReport.CourseID` because it's already part of the `SectionID, CourseID` foreign key to `Section`, and `Section.CourseID` can be trusted because of the `Section` table's foreign key with `Course`.